# OpenType Kerkis and bold Small Caps with greek

Tags: fonts, fontspec, small-caps, bold

[Kerkis](http://iris.math.aegean.gr/kerkis/) font is an OpenType font that has Greek glyphs Small Caps both for regular and bold shapes. The names of the OTF files are `KerkisSmallCaps.otf` and `KerkisSmallCaps-Bold.otf`.

When I compile the following example, the `textbf` is ignored. This is not surprising, as only the regular font is declared.

If I replace `KerkisSmallCaps` with `KerkisSmallCaps-Bold` then (obviously) the bold shape is used for both lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
    UprightFont = Kerkis,
    ItalicFont = KerkisItalics,
    SlantedFont = KerkisItalics,
    BoldFont = Kerkisb,
    BoldItalicFont = Kerkisbi,
    BoldSlantedFont = Kerkisbi,
    SmallCapsFont = KerkisSmallCaps]
    {Kerkis}

\begin{document}
\textsc{κείμενο στα ελληνικά}

\textbf{\textsc{κείμενο στα ελληνικά}}
\end{document}
```

The question is, how can I make xelatex typeset the first sentence in the regular shape and the second sentence in the bold one? What options should be passed at fontspec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess bold small caps is so uncommon that the fontspec authors didn't consider it. As a workaround you could separately define a new font command for bold small caps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    UprightFont = Kerkis,
    ItalicFont = KerkisItalics,
    SlantedFont = KerkisItalics,
    BoldFont = Kerkisb,
    BoldItalicFont = Kerkisbi,
    BoldSlantedFont = Kerkisbi,
    SmallCapsFont = KerkisSmallCaps]
    {Kerkis}

\newfontface\bfsc{KerkisSmallCaps-Bold}

\begin{document}
\textsc{κείμενο στα ελληνικά}

{\bfsc κείμενο στα ελληνικά}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I know that it is a rather obscure choice, but I was fooling with fontspec and I couldn't figure  out how to do it. I thought about creating a new fontface but I believed that there would be an option. If nothing else comes up, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @pmav: Maybe Will or Khaled see this and can shed some light on the absence of a `BoldSmallCapsFont` option.