# Foreign-Language support in \part, \Section, etc

Tags: luatex, koma-script, fontspec, polyglossia

I have a document with a lot of different languages, some of which appear in \part{}, \section{}, etc. blocks. For example, the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily \bfseries}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=poly]{greek}
\usepackage{xstring}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{SBL Greek}
\tracinglostchars=2

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{Analysis Part Six: Anestis Logothetis{\textemdash}{\begin{greek}\textsc{Άναστάσεις}\end{greek}}}

Some text about {\begin{greek}\textsc{Άναστάσεις}\end{greek}}

\end{document}
```

For me, the word "Άναστάσεις" is properly set by \textsc in the body text, but not in the title. If I try language setting in other languages (I have another section title with German) the "Part" name is preceded by "Titlegerman" (indicating that the "\end{german} part just got appended to "Title").

Short version of the question: is there a way to have foreign-language words properly typeset in \part, \chapter, \section, etc. blocks? And to appear this way in the TOC?

Additionally, I should point out that Noto Sans doesn't handle \textsc correctly at all for Greek scripts, which is why I'm sticking with SBL Greek here.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Seems that SBL Greek does not have bold small caps, so you only get bold in the `\part` title. In the document body, the text is not bold, so you get small caps. You need a font that has bold Greek small caps (not sure if there are any fonts out there that have that). This has nothing to do with the language as such, this is a font issue. I could not reproduce any language switching issues, but I'd probably prefer `\text<language>{...}` over `\begin{<language>}...\end{<language>}` in the argument of a title: `\textgreek{\textsc{Άναστάσεις}}`

Comment: As a matter of fact, the Kerkis font both has a boldface smallcaps style _and_ is part of texlive. I'll see about making it work. If there a way to specify that one font type _just_ for the boldface smallcaps that would be used in titles?

Comment: Edit: I found a way to implement it in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17096/opentype-kerkis-and-bold-small-caps-with-greek). That solves the problem (though I would have preferred a SemiBoldSmallCaps, as the Bold is too thick), so I'm good. Thanks!